# How to uninstall swiftlint from xcode, or to turn its warnings off

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftlint

Please help me to understand how to uninstal swiftlint, or how to switch it warnings off completely(because it starts to ignore all rules from time to time).
I installed swiftilnt from pkg file, and now cannot find a way to remove it. 
"run from Makefile" solution does not help me, because i don't understand where it is, and how to run it.
In Xcode preferences i also can't find a way to uninstall it. Also i search in finder for "swiftlint", and it cannot find it too.

Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Have you looked at the github page? https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> If you want to have a possibility to control which rule is disabled/enabled and to set thresholds for warnings and errors for a given rule, just create a .swiftlint.yml file in your project directory...

Take a look at this article:

https://swifting.io/blog/2016/03/29/11-swiftlint/

Answer (score 15):

Try this :

1. Go to your Project in the Navigation area (left column, blue icon on the very top)
2. Select your app target in the Targets line.
3. Go "Build Phases" tab
4. In Run Script, delete the command line under "Shell" text field that looks like this: (You can also just comment a line by adding # at the start of it, as mentioned below)

   ```
    if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
    swiftlint
    else
    echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from 
    https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
    fi
   ```
5. Build Again to check !

This works for me and has the advantage to put it back later very easily.
Hope it helps

Comment: This is a clean and correct answer. I'd simply comment these lines rather than removing them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts of the question:

1. How to uninstall Swiftlint from Xcode?

   a. If you have installed SwiftLint from a **package installer**, then:

   ```
   rm -rf "/Library/Frameworks/SwiftLintFramework.framework"
   rm -f "/usr/local/bin/swiftlint"
   ```

   b. If you have installed through **homebrew** then:

   ```
   brew unlink swiftlint
   brew uninstall --force swiftlint
   ```
2. Turn its warnings off,-

   a. If you want to turn off any specific warning/error please prefer the **SwiftLint rule**

   This is the nice document https://swifting.io/blog/2016/03/29/11-swiftlint/ suggested by @Andriy

   b. If you want to completely switch it off, remove this from the shell script:

   ```
   if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
       swiftlint
   else
       echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
   fi
   ```

   Added it again whenever required.

Comment: This helped me, I had 2 versions of Swiftlint installed. After removing the one from Xcode it started using the one from Homebrew